# Pandas: How to use (df.groupby) in a lambda formula

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

The example below:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c']
list2 = range(len(list1))
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(list1, list2), columns=  ['Item','Value'])
df
```

gives:

[image]

required: GroupFirstValue column as shown below.

[image]

The idea is to use a lambda formula to get the 'first' value for each group..for example "a"'s first value is 0, "b"'s first value is 3, "c"'s first value is 7. That's why those numbers appear in the GroupFirstValue column.

Note: I know that I can do this on 2 steps...one is the original df and the second is a grouped by df and then merge them together. The idea is to see if this can be done more efficiently in a single step. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groupby and use first

```
df.groupby('Item')['Value'].first()
```

or you can use transform and assign to a new column in your frame

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('Item')['Value'].transform('first')
```

Comment: That's even better than what I needed! you've cut like 20 lines of code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `mask` and `duplicated`

```
df['GroupFirstValue'] = df.Value.mask(df.Item.duplicated())

Out[109]:
  Item  Value  GroupFirstValue
0    a      0              0.0
1    a      1              NaN
2    a      2              NaN
3    b      3              3.0
4    b      4              NaN
5    b      5              NaN
6    b      6              NaN
7    c      7              7.0
8    c      8              NaN
9    c      9              NaN
```